# How to compress files larger than a certain size in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

The idea behind this code is to find all files within a directory larger than 1KB (or 1000 bytes), compress them, and delete them from the original directory. I was able to figure out both of the separate commands but am unsure how to link the output from the first to the second commands (if that makes sense)? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
# Initialize variables
dir=~/Test 

# Change directory to $DIRECTORY
cd "$dir"

# Find all files in the current directory that are larger than 1000 bytes (1KB).
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000c | zip -mT backup
```

Comment: Also see [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provided a stub before, but I decided to flesh out the script. This still won't handle pathological cases such as filenames containing wildcards.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# the following line handles filenames with spaces
IFS='
'
backupfilename=backup;

for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000c)
do
  if zip ${backupfilename} -u "${file}" # test that zip succeeded
  then
     echo "added file ${file} to zip archive ${backupfilename}" 1>&2;
     # add your remove command here; remember to use quotes "${filename}"
     echo "file ${file} has been deleted" 1>&2;
  fi
done
```

The only thing I have left out is the delete command. You should work that out yourself and test it carefully to be sure you don't accidentally delete files you didn't want to delete.

Comment: Doing it this way, you could also test whether the archiving command succeeded before deleting the file that was supposed to be added to the archive.

Comment: This will fail if the directory has any files with white spaces or wild card in them - because of word splitting and globbing.

Comment: To handle filenames with spaces, add the line ...
IFS='
'
... before the for loop. That says to use only new lines to separate file names. I'll have to look into filenames with wildcards.

Comment: `set -f` can suppress globbing.

Comment: My last comment wasn't formatted properly: the new line was stripped out. It should read IFS='<new line>'. In some shells you can also use IFS='\n'.

Comment: I completely rewrote my original post. It takes into account the problem of file names with spaces mentioned by coreforester.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-exec` option instead of trying to pipe the next command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000c -exec zip -mT backup {} \;
```

Would create a `zip` archive containing the matched files.

Comment: Reviewing the man page for find, I should've realized that was an option. Thank you! I'm getting an error now, `find: paths must precede expression`- my path should just be the . (current directory), which definitely precedes the expression, so any ideas on why it's springing that error?

Comment: It sounds like there's some shell expansion taking place, generally this error happens if something (like a path, variable, etc.) is not quoted properly; other reasons exist also, but need more specific details ...

Answer (score 0):

Use xargs to pass each line in the output of find as zip argument:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000c | xargs -I f zip -mT backup f
```

Also you can use a while loop to do the same:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +1000c | while read f ; do zip -mT backup $f ; done
```